# I am getting NoSuchMethodError: com.oracle.bmc.ClientConfiguration.getRetryConfiguration with weblogic server

Tags: weblogic12c, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

I am using 
`implementation (group: 'com.oracle.oci.sdk', name: 'oci-java-sdk-dataflow', version: '1.12.5')` to use create an application in OCI dataflow. But it's not working and getting below error:

```
"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.oracle.bmc.ClientConfiguration.getRetryConfiguration()Lcom/oracle/bmc/retrier/RetryConfiguration;",
        "com.oracle.bmc.ClientConfiguration.getRetryConfiguration()Lcom/oracle/bmc/retrier/RetryConfiguration;",
        "[org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1053), org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942), org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005), org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:908),
```

I can see 3 jars related to OCI in \WEB-INF\lib path
[image]

Comment: No code, no logs, no information about versions, etc... How can welp you with so few information about your issue ? Provide more information to be able to help you.

Comment: look carefully. version detail is there, version: '1.12.5'. Log is also shared at the first place with error details. I expect you to read the question completely before jumping in, to react. And why do you need code to understand the noMethodFound error thing ?

Comment: I did. What is the WebLogic server version ? Post the complete error log message including the full stack trace plz.

Answer (score -1):

run mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose and see what version you have

Make sure the versions are all consistent. In this case, I suspect that oci-java-sdk-dataflow is using an older version of oci-java-sdk-common than it expects.

If older version of oci-java-sdk-common is getting added in the class path from a dependent module exclude it to get this issue resolved.

duplicate jar would be my next guess